# Is there something like str() of Python in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Is there something like str() and execute() of Python in PHP.

In python we have the following code:

```
 car_date="2018-08-0"+str(car_dealership)
 car.execute("INSERT INTO cars(car_id,car_price,car_dealership_id) VALUES ('"+car_id+"','"+car_price+"',2,'"+str(car_dealership)+"')");
 db2.commit()
```

What' about in php (Laravel)

Comment: When posting conversion questions here, clearly state EXACTLY what the original code does and what the new code does that showing why it is not the same, as its unlikely you will find experts in both languages.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strval()` will work like `str()`

For `.execute` you would use something like...

```
DB::connection('mysql')->statement("<sql command here>");
```